Is the Wirtinger derivative just $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?
Let $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, z \mapsto w $ be holomorphic, and $ z = x + iy $ and $ w = u +iv $.
$$ \begin{align} 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u +iv) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \\[1.5 mm]
    & = \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\bigg) \hspace{1cm} \text{Doubling} \\[1.5 mm]
    & = \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\bigg) \hspace{1cm} \text{Cauchy-Riemann Equations} \\[1.5 mm]
    & = \frac{1}{2} \Bigg( \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \bigg) u + i\bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg)v \Bigg) \\[1.5 mm]
    & = \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \bigg) (u + iv) \\[1.5 mm]
    & = \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \bigg)f(z) \ := \ \frac{df}{dz}
\end{align} $$
It seems weird to go to such lengths to get a complicated definition for $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. $\ $  Why not just say $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} $? $\ $ Is it often easier to compute?

This derivative applies to non-holomorphic functions to, but yes, it is equal for holomorphic ones.

Which derivative applies to non-holomorphic functions?  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, $\frac{1}{2} \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \bigg)f(z)$, or $ \frac{df}{dz}$?  I thought the last two are defined (weird notation) to be the same thing.  And to equate them to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ requires using the Cauchy Riemann equalities, implying that they are holomorphic.  So do you mean the first one, that we can take $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ as if it were a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$?

If the last two are the same thing, all three apply to non-holomorphic functions. And the first two are equal only for holomorphic functions.

But I usually see (and your title agrees with me) the Wirtinger derivative written using $\partial$, not $d$.

Ah, so the Wirtinger derivative should be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$, not $\frac{df}{dz}$?  And all three can be performed on non-holomorphic functions from $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where the derivative $\frac{df}{dz}$ does not exist?

Do $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{df}{dz}$ behave differently or give different answers?  I guess the difference between partial and normal derivatives eludes me when the function only has one variable, $z$.  Would they both give me the answers I would "expect"?  Ex. for $f(z) = z^n + \ln(z)$ I'd expect $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{df}{dz} = nz^{n-1} + \frac{1}{z}$.  Except I'm not allowed to write $\frac{df}{dz}$ if it's not complex-differentiable (satisfies CRE)?

$ \newcommand{\z}{\overline{z}} 
  \newcommand{\Rt}{\mathbb{R}^2}
\newcommand{\dx}[1][]{ \frac{\partial #1}{\partial x} }
\newcommand{\dy}[1][]{ \frac{\partial #1}{\partial y} }
\newcommand{\dz}[1][]{ \frac{\partial #1}{\partial z} }
\newcommand{\dzc}[1][]{ \frac{\partial #1}{\partial \z} }
$
I have collected some information.
$1.\ $ Some facts.
There are at least four derivatives: $\displaystyle \  \dx, \ \partial_W := \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \dx - i\dy \bigg), \ \dz, \ \text{and} \ \frac{d}{dz}  $.
$ \partial_x$, $\partial_W$, and $\partial_z $ are partial       derivatives that can be taken even when the function is not complex      differentiable.
$ \partial_W = \partial_z$ always, whether or not the function is complex-differentiable. $\ $ This can be derived (2 below).
$ \partial_x = \partial_W$ IFF $f$ is complex differentiable.
$ \partial_z = d_z $  only if the function is complex-differentiable. $\ $ This is equivalent to saying that $f$ can be written as a function of only $z$ and not of $\z$, or of $z$ and $x$ or $y$. $\ $ So $ f = x = \frac{1}{2}(z + \z) $ because it cannae be written solely as a function of z.
$2.\ $ Derive that $ \partial_W = \partial_x .\ $ Without using the Cauchy-Riemann equations or assuming that the function is complex-differentiable.
Letting $z : \Rt \rightarrow \mathbb{C},\ z(x,y) = x + iy $, we have
$$ 
\begin{align} 
& z = x + iy  \qquad   & \z = x - iy \\[1mm]
& \dx[z] = 1  \qquad   & \dx[\z] = 1 \\[1mm]
& \dy[z] = i  \qquad   & \dy[\z] = -i
\end{align} $$
$$ 
\begin{align}
\partial_W f(z,\z) &= \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \dz[f]\dx[z] + \dzc[f]\dx[\z] - i\dz[f]\dy[z] - i\dzc[f]\dy[\z] \bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \bigg( \dz[f] + \dzc[f] - i^2\dz[f] + i^2\dzc[f] \bigg) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \bigg( 2\dz[f] + \dzc[f] (1 - 1) \bigg) \\
&= \dz[f]
\end{align} $$
So we see that $\partial_W = \partial_z$ and that $\partial_W$ ignores any part of the function that depends on $z$. $\ $  Ex. If $ f(z,\z) = g(z) + h(\z) $ then $ \partial_W f = g'(z) $. $\ $  Similarly, we see that $ \displaystyle \partial_\overline{W} := \frac{1}{2} \bigg(\dx + i \dy \bigg) $ ignores any part that depends on $z$ instead of $\z$:
$$ \partial_\overline{W} f = \frac{1}{2} \big(g'(z)\big(1 - i(i) \big) + h'(\z) \big(1 + i(-i) \big) \big) 
= h'(\z) $$
I like this proof because where most proofs use the Cauchy-Riemann substitutions to show that $\partial_x = \partial_W $, and then just define $\partial_z = \partial_W $, as if it were just notation, this one actually directly shows that $ \partial_W = \partial_z $.

I will leave this up for a while before accepting it in case anyone has feedback.
